# Calling git -C /path/to/dir from python fails, runs from console

Tags: python, git, ubuntu

I am writing a git serverside hook that needs to check if there are any modifications to a different git folder (different from the bare git repository in which that hook resides). To that end, I have written a `pre-receive` hook and I am trying to use `git status --porcelain`. The script has to select the folder which needed checking, but for now i decided to hardcode all the paths, until I make it work.

So far, when i run this hook as just a python script, it gives me the correct result, but when i run it as a hook, it gives me an error.

**UPD** It might also be worth mentioning that the script is executed on an Ubuntu Linux machine. Might be there any limitations on what can be run from pyton or what processes can be started by other processes?**/UPD**

Here is the script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess
import string
import os

print "PRE-RECEIVE HOOK >>>"

def git(args):
    dirname = os.path.dirname("/home/git/repos/branchone/gitremote/")
    print "Dirname = " + dirname
    pr = subprocess.Popen( ["git","-C", dirname,  "status", "--porcelain"], shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    (details, error) = pr.communicate()
    print details, error
    details = details.strip()
    if error != "":
        print "Errors: " + error
        return None
    return details

def pwd():
    pwd = subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    details = pwd.stdout.read().strip()
    print "PWD:. " + details

def main():
    git([])
    pwd()

if \__name__ == "\__main__":
    main()

sys.exit(2)
```

Here is how i call it from cosole:

```
root@remine-vm:/home/git/repos/gitremote.git# ./hooks/pre-receive
PRE-RECEIVE HOOK >>>
Dirname = /home/git/repos/branchone/gitremote
 M eden
?? fruit
?? snake
```

Here's the response when I try to push something to the remote:

```
Push: Not all refs have been pushed.
$ git.exe push --porcelain --progress --recurse-submodules=check origin refs/heads/branchone:refs/heads/branchone
'branchone' rejected (non-fast-forward)
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: PRE-RECEIVE HOOK >>>
remote: Dirname = /home/git/repos/branchone/gitremote
remote:  fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: 
remote: Errors: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: 
remote: PWD:. /home/git/repos/gitremote.git
error: failed to push some refs to 'root@redmine-vm:/home/git/repos/gitremote.git'
```

Comment: edit submitted but note that the title uses git -c instead of git -C - lowecase and uppercase flags do different things in git

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding more keys to the git command, namely specifying the path to the git dir and the working tree.

    `pr = subprocess.Popen( ["git","--git-dir", "/home/git/repos/branchone/gitremote/.git", "--work-tree", "/home/git/repos/branchone/gitremote", "-C", dirname, "status", "--porcelain"], shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )`

This article was extremely helpful: http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/